# Dockerized NodeJS API can't connect to a MySQL container, getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: api
    container_name: app-api
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./.env
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    volumes:
      - ./src
      - ./node_modules
    command: yarn start
    depends_on:
      - mysql
  mysql:
    container_name: app-mysql
    restart: always
    image: mysql:8.0.21
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
      MYSQL_USER: 'app'
      MYSQL_PASS: 'password'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'appdb'
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - '3307:3306'
```

My `.env` looks like this:

```
DB_HOST="mysql" // Tried 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0
DB_PORT="3306"
DB_USER="app"
DB_PASSWORD="password"
DB_NAME="appdb"
NODE_ENV="DEV"
```

Error I'm getting from the service:
`{"message":"Database connection failed with error Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND \"mysql\"","level":"info","timestamp":"2020-07-27T03:57:55.524Z"}`

I can connect with `root` from MySQL Workbench, I can't connect with user `app`. If the api is started without being in a docker container, it can connect to local db.

Seems like it just can't resolve the host at all, is this a DNS issue? I can't remember if I had the same issue when mysql wasn't dockerized, but it couldn't connect to a db that is outside a container. What am I doing wrong.

Edit: commenting out the whole `mysql` service has no impact at all, error message is same.

Comment: Try to use the service name as host: `app-mysql` And make sure the DB is running when the service is trying to connect.

Comment: What code is connecting to the database?  Are you trying to do something like run database migrations in your Dockerfile (that will fail with this error)?

Comment: @abestrad I thought the service name is `mysql` in this case, `app-mysql` is just the container name? DB should be running, I have a `depends_on` config added to the api service, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @DavidMaze 

I'm using this boilerplate:
https://github.com/a7urag/node-express-mysql-typescript-api-boilerplate


It does have auto sync that attempts to do migration.


`Dockerfile` itself doesn't have any relevant commands and `yarn start` (in `docker-compose`) does this:
`"start": "nodemon src/index.js"`

So migration could be failing, maybe because of the volumes:


`volumes: - ./data:/var/lib/mysql`

There's no `data` folder.

Comment: `depends_on` will help you with the bootstrap order, but won't help you to wait until the service is running and able to get requests. For the latter you will need something like wait-for-it.sh, and configure it to wait until the db is up. `docker network inspect <<yournet>>` will show you the containers list and the names that can be used as host.

Comment: @abestrad I ran the mysql container with `--no-deps` to make sure it's running, then I ran  the api service with `--no-deps -d`. MySQL was up and I could connect from workbench. The api service container could also `ping mysql`. I also tried removing the mysql container and just running a windows service, error message was the same.

Answer (score 5):

I built a simpler API service to test the setup -- it's working correctly. Must've been something with the boilerplate API I was using.

If anybody's looking, things I discovered:

- It's a better to have a user-defined network, then add that network to both services
- If api's to connect to a localhost (machine) MySQL, setting the host to `host.docker.internal` instead of `127.0.0.1` or `mysql` works -- connects to a db server on your machine.
- `./data` folder was actually not empty, `mysql` dumped all its stuff there it seems like.

Answer (score 5):

Docker interprets double quotes in a .env file differently than a unix system.   Specifically - double quotes are considered part of the string.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/

> There is no special handling of quotation marks. This means that they are part of the VAL.

Remove the quotes in your .env file and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. I am using Docker Secrets via docker-compose to load the mysql host into my Node app and had a newline at the end of my secret file for the mysql hostname.

... sooo, in case you are using Docker Secrets, you might want to check if there is an unwanted newline at the end of your secret file.

Answer (score 0):

had same question finally resolved . cause

```
docker create network xxx
```

just network layer

```
docker run -d --network xxx --network-alias xxx-host
  -v todo-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql \
  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret \
  -e MYSQL_DATABASE=todos \
  mysql:5.7
```

not obviously in document.
network just a layer. network-alias is host.
so we start our app through network host.
we need to pass host use network-alias.

> https://docs.docker.com/get-started/07_multi_container/